# How to handle Java Objects when they are received from channel

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to send serialized Java objects to remote RabbitMQ client. I'm interested what are the best practices when Object is received and must be processed. I tried this code:

```
channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, ROUTING_KEY, null, SerializationUtils.serialize(new SomecustomObj()));
```

Java code to handle the receiving logic:

```
public QueueConsumer() throws Exception {

        try {
            Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
                @Override
                public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                        byte[] body) throws IOException {
                    traslateObj(SerializationUtils.deserialize(body));
                }
            };
            channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void traslateObj(Object obj) {      
        if (obj instanceof TransactionsBean) {
            /// do something
        }
        if (obj instanceof NotesBean) {
            /// do something
        }       
    }
```

Can you share your experience is it better to use `instanceof` in order to navigate the Java object to appropriate processing or some other way like using `HashMap` with key and custom Object.

Can you share some ideas.

Comment: best is to only send one type of object per queue.

Comment: Very good answer this came to me also several minutes ago.

Comment: @mavriksc just in case are there any other good practices?